# Compare 2 csv files and merge common field records into 1st file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I'm trying to write a shell script / bash command that will compare 2 csv files using the 3rd field in csv (starting with 91), 1st file having millions of records and second file, a smaller one having thousands of data. If there is match found in 2nd file by comparing the 3rd field in 1st file, then the matching records in 2nd file (smaller one) should replace the record in 1st file or create a 3rd file that will have matching records from 2nd file replacing the matching records in 1st file.

I'm trying something like this but doesn't give the required output: grep -v -f file2.csv file1.csv

CSV file1:

```
0,104673081,91623178295,false,2019-03-21 03:31:04,2019-03-24 13:18:03
0,104673361,91678296502,false,2019-03-21 03:35:35,2019-05-22 21:55:50
0,104679130,**91661560977**,false,2019-03-21 03:36:37,2019-03-21 03:37:00
0,104674082,91691721155,false,2019-03-21 03:49:07,2019-06-21 08:13:00
```

CSV file2:

```
0,104673063,91623178427,false,2019-03-21 03:31:04,2019-03-24 13:18:03
0,104673321,91678296913,false,2019-03-21 03:35:35,2019-05-22 21:55:50
0,104679111,**91661560977**,false,2019-03-21 03:36:37,2019-03-21 04:34:00
```

Expected output :

file 1 (matching record from 2nd file by comparing 3rd field ie. 91661560977 from 2nd file has replaced the record in 1st file)

```
0,104673081,91623178295,false,2019-03-21 03:31:04,2019-03-24 13:18:03
0,104673361,91678296502,false,2019-03-21 03:35:35,2019-05-22 21:55:50
0,104679111,**91661560977**,false,2019-03-21 03:36:37,2019-03-21 04:34:00
0,104674082,91691721155,false,2019-03-21 03:49:07,2019-06-21 08:13:00
```

Comment: Please do add 2 things in your question. 1- Sample of BOTH Input files in CODE TAGS. 2- Sample of expected output in CODE TAGS, once done kindly do let us know in comment section here.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, the details are added as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next}$3 in a{$0=a[$3]}1' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
0,104673081,91623178295,false,2019-03-21 03:31:04,2019-03-24 13:18:03
0,104673361,91678296502,false,2019-03-21 03:35:35,2019-05-22 21:55:50
0,104679111,**91661560977**,false,2019-03-21 03:36:37,2019-03-21 04:34:00
0,104674082,91691721155,false,2019-03-21 03:49:07,2019-06-21 08:13:00
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F, '         # comma delimiter
NR==FNR {           # process first file, ie. file2
    a[$3]=$0        # hash record, $3 is the key NOTICE NEEDS TO BE UNIQUE
    next            # process next record
}
$3 in a {           # process second file, if matching $3 found in both files
    $0=a[$3]        # replace record with the one from file2
}1' file2 file1     # output. mind the file order to hash the smaller fie
```

If you want to dump the rest of the `file2`as well:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$0;next}$3 in a{$0=a[$3];delete a[$3]}1; END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file2 file1
```

Comment: Okay, But are we not merging the non-matching records from file 2 to file 1 as well.

Comment: _are we not merging the non-matching records from file 2 to file 1 as well_ The script only replaces the lines in `file1` (while outputing the lines to stdout) with those lines from `file2` that have equal `$3` so _we are not merging the non-matching records from file 2 to file 1_. I didn't see such a requirement nor does the expected output reflect that.

Comment: @JamesBrown, yes I second you sir, this is added later now.

Comment: Easy to implement, thou: _remove element from `a[]` when used and in the `END{}` `print` the rest of `a[]`_.

Comment: Half asleep myself. and its only 2300 (why the night is still so young, tried fixing an gawk |& c-program last night till 0500 and failed so time to sleep). Maybe instead of just `delete`ing used element, copy it to another array `b[]`, `delete` from `a[]` and check existance from both. Then in the `END` just print from `a[]`. I'd try to avoid `sort`ing the large file.